# SWT and Swing on mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, swt

I can't seem to run **SWT** and **Swing** together on a mac.

I understand that to run Swt on a mac I must pass argument `-XstartOnFirstThread` however that seems to break **Swing**.

This is a simple snippet that I wrote. None of them create any windows yes, but they use code neccessary for **SWT** initialization and **Swing** initialization.

```
public class Snippet
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            System.out.println("Muhahahaha");
         }
      });

      Display display = new Display();
      display.dispose();
   }
}
```

If you execute it with the `-XstartOnFirstThread` you will observe that the program never finishes executing.

How can I get both of them to run in a harmony and execute to the end?

Thanks to anyone for any help. I spent a week without managing to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Running **Swing** and **SWT** together isn't such a good practice. These two are completely different(logically speaking), and you should choose only one of them to go further with(note that **SWT** is more customizable and tries to combine the best from **AWT** and **Swing**, while **Swing** is more limited and uses the platform`s native widgets). Perhaps [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/04/swing-vs-swt-side-by-side-comparison/) will help you change your mind.

However, if you are really serious about using them together you should bare in mind that you should not mix them in the same window, and things should be working just fine.

Best of luck!